# Jekyll: Page not parsing custom variable from layout

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I've just begun learning Jekyll and I've run into a little speedbump.

I have 2 layouts in my `_layout` folder which essentially look like this:-

**default.html**

```
<html>
<head> <!-- Meta Tags etc --> </head>
<body>
    {{ content }}
</body>
</html>
```

**hero.html**

```
---
layout: default
---
<section id="hero">
    <h3>{{ hero.descr }}</h3>
</section>
{{ content }}
```

My index page extends the hero layout as follows:-

**index.html**

```
---
layout: hero
descr: Hello there.
---
```

The layouts work just fine, and the website appears as it should, except for the **hero.descr** variable. The heading tag is just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow of **data** is uni-directional.
`default.html` => `hero.html` => `index.html`

`hero.html` will not know what's defined in `index.html`

But, the **rendering is in the opposite direction** (inserted into the `{{ content }}` variable of the parent.

`index.html` ==> `hero.html` ==> `default.html`

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? hero.html is just the layout with a placeholder variable that's populated by the front-matter of the index.html page.

Comment: In that context, almost true.. the placeholder variable is `{{ content }}`. Everything else is ***inherited*** from the parent

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the variable `{{ hero.descr }}` does not exist. I think that it should be `{{ page.descr }}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After reading yours and ashmaroli's answer, I went back to the docs and studied them thoroughly and realised my fundamental understanding of how Jekyll variables and layouts work was incorrect. Probably should have familiarised myself with Liquid first. Anyways, yes, you are absolutely correct, {{ page.descr }} is the proper way to declare a custom variable for a page. :)